# SQL Formula - value of field is twice the old value of field

Tags: mysql, sql, netsuite

I am trying to find a formula for a search that pulls any items twice the value it was before.

I don't know any SQL formulas and am looking for any guidance.

```
{systemnotes.newvalue} is twice the value in {systemnotes.oldvalue}
```

Comment: `where {systemnotes.newvalue} = {systemnotes.oldvalue} * 2` I assume you're trying to do something a bit more complicated than that, if so, please rephrase your question.

Comment: Its quite unclear what you are looking for.  Could you post example data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Just perform the comparison in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM systemnotes
WHERE newvalue = oldvalue * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit rusty on my SQL but I think this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT NewValue
FROM SystemNotes
WHERE NewValue = OldValue*2
```